# Address of address of a variable

Tags: c, pointers

I was experimenting the behaviors of pointer in C. I wrote the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main(){
    int a = 1;
    printf("%p\n", &&a);
}
```

I knew that this program would give error. Because an address of address would be ambiguous and this would become extremely recursive. But when I tried to compile the program, it gave an error which I couldn't understand.

> error: label ‘a’ used but not defined
>
> printf("%p\n", &&a);

What does it mean by `label ‘a’ used but not defined`?

Comment: *"I was experimenting the behaviors of pointer in C"* Don't do that, that will not teach you anything useful. Read a good book instead; preferably one not from the 90s when `main` without a return type used to be legal.

Comment: You cannot get the address of the address of `int a` because `&a` might not even *be* in memory - it could be in a register.

Comment: I know I cannot get the address of the address. My question is about the error given. What is the meaning of `label ‘a’ used but not defined`?

Comment: Because `a` is a variable, not a label (GCC extension)?

Comment: Use `printf("%p\n", & &a);` to attempt the address of an address.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`&&` is real `gcc` extension, but not for variables. Its for labels.

`&&a` is used to [get the address of a label defined in the current function](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html).

In your case compiler deduced that `a`, followed by `&&` operator, is `label`, but you haven't any `label` `a` defined in your code, so that is the error.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't really a direct answer to your question.  It's more for anyone reading wondering why you can't take an address of an address when such things as `char **ptr;` can be defined.

An address doesn't *have* an address.  Only actual variables in memory have an address.  You can put an address in a pointer variable (as noted in other answers here), and then the *pointer variable* will have an address, but the address value held in the pointer doesn't inherently have its own address.

An address is effectively "where something is".  Trying to find the address of an address is like trying to ask "Where is where is my car?"

So `char **ptr;` isn't the address of an address, it's a variable that contains the address of a pointer *variable*.

Comment: "Where is where is my car?" --> "There, there" ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You are not allowed to take the address of an rvalue-temporary returned by the address operator. && is a gcc-extension:
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html

Answer (score 1):

it quite logical the address is not something which exists somewhere physical in the memory - so it cant have the address itself. That is the reason the `&&` operator could be used for other purposes.

if you try

```
int x ;
printf("%d\n", &x); // valid
printf("%d\n", &(&x));  // error lvalue required as the address is not the object
```

Answer (score 0):

& is just to get the adresse of the memory box try to use pointers .

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointers.htm